# exception when trying to retrieve user's friends

Tags: android, parse-platform, facebook-android-sdk

I'm trying to get on login action user's friends list with the following code:

```
Request request = Request.newMyFriendsRequest(ParseFacebookUtils.getSession(), new Request.GraphUserListCallback() {

@Override
public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> users, Response response) {

    // not interesting logic
}

});

request.executeAndWait();
```

and after I'm calling a function that runs the code I'm getting the following exception:

```
04-14 00:39:55.896  25106-25106/com.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.app, PID: 25106
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLOutputStream.write(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:724)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushInternal(BufferedOutputStream.java:185)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:85)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.flushRequest(HttpTransport.java:107)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:642)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:347)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:503)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:136)
        at com.facebook.Response.fromHttpConnection(Response.java:301)
        at com.facebook.Request.executeConnectionAndWait(Request.java:1565)
        at com.facebook.Request.executeBatchAndWait(Request.java:1464)
        at com.facebook.Request.executeBatchAndWait(Request.java:1433)
        at com.facebook.Request.executeBatchAndWait(Request.java:1415)
        at com.facebook.Request.executeAndWait(Request.java:1387)
        at com.facebook.Request.executeAndWait(Request.java:1269)
        at com.app.LoginActivity.getFriends(LoginActivity.java:187)
```

Why does it happens, and how can I get user friends list without making it as Async task?

Comment: private Runnable doBackgroundThreadProcessing = new Runnable() {
public void run() {
request.executeAndWait();
}
};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
request.executeAndWait();
```

try using

```
request.executeAsync();
```

Reference [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/Request/#executeAsync).

Basically `executeAndWait()` must be called from a background thread while `executeAsync()` can be called from the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, you're right about that, but is there anyway that I can do it on UI thread? It's part of registration validations, and I want by the results to do an action.

Comment: @MichaelArenzon I'm not sure what you mean? Calling `executeAsync` allows you to run it on the UI thread and the response is then in the `onComplete` method

Comment: I think I'm having an idea about that. Thanks again for the reply

Comment: @MichaelArenzon You can put that code in the onComplete so that it it only executes when done. Same as doing it with the onPostExecute of an AsyncTask. Hope this helps.